# RIght aligning text div inside img element

Tags: html, css

I am having a very simple structure as follows:

```
<div class="inline">
    <div class="photo-group thumb_wrapper">
      <img  src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYZ35nsT0CRTlGBtNmPHikH74wXBldsPe8LQYfhXnzADYo-xSU"
           />
      <div class="thumb_icon label-inverse">
        <p class="thumb_icon_content">
                243 x 324    
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb_time label-inverse" ><p                 class="thumb_time_content">11.41 Kb</p></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/nomekagojo/3/edit?html,css,output

i want to have the `.thumb_icon_content` left align on the img and the `.thumb_time_content` right aligned on the img. the main issue is that 
the img doesn't always takes up 100% of the the `.photo-group` div.
if I would put width:100% on the img, it will be OK but i want to display the img without changing it's resolution.

How can i achieve it?

any help will be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want content on the image, you need to have it positioned absolute;

```
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.thumb_icon_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.thumb_time {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! actualy what did the trick is the inline-block. it was inline.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you:

```
 p.thumb_time_content {float:right;}
 .inline {display:inline-block;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmap709n/)

`display:inline-block;` will prevent parent div from stretching and wraps it around content.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.thumb_wrapper {
    display: table;
}
.thumb-caption{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.thumb-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.thumb_time p{
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
    <div class="photo-group thumb_wrapper">
        
        <div class="thumb-cell">              
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYZ35nsT0CRTlGBtNmPHikH74wXBldsPe8LQYfhXnzADYo-xSU" />        
       
        
        
        <div class="thumb-caption">
            <div class="thumb_icon thumb-cell label-inverse">
                <p class="thumb_icon_content">243 x 324</p>     </div>
            <div class="thumb_time thumb-cell label-inverse">
                <p class="thumb_time_content">11.41 Kb</p>
            </div>            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/boyotisifo/1/)**

```
.inline{
  width:250px;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  content:"";
}
.thumb_time_content {float:right;}
 .thumb_icon {float:left;}
```